# How to ignore duplicates from a list and add one item instead?

Tags: java, android, algorithm

If two or more users have same height and weight, then ignore these items and add one item and set name multiple. I try code below but I can't delete same items.

**Info.class**

```
public class Info {

    public String name;
    public int height;
    public int weight;

    public Info(String name,int height, int weight) {
        this.height = height;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.name=name;
    }
}
```

**Main.class**

```
    List<Info> infoList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Info> infoListFiltered = new ArrayList<>();

    infoList.add(new Info("a",1, 2));
    infoList.add(new Info("b",2, 2));
    infoList.add(new Info("c",1, 3));
    infoList.add(new Info("d",1, 2));
    infoList.add(new Info("e",1, 2));



    for (int i = 0; i < infoList.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < infoList.size(); j++) {
            if(infoList.get(i).height==infoList.get(j).height&&infoList.get(i).weight==infoList.get(j).weight) {
                infoList.get(i).name="multi";
                infoListFiltered.add(infoList.get(i));
            }else {
                infoListFiltered.add(infoList.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: either use a collection that doesn't allow duplicates, or write your own add method addToList(Object o) { if ( !myList.contains(o)) myList.add(o); }

Comment: You are always adding to the list and not removing items. You are comparing current height and weight to the next item height and weight but instead of deleting you are adding again. are you sure thats what you want to do?

Comment: implement `hashCode` and `equals` methods, use `HashSet` if order does not matter, or `LinkedHashSet` if insertion order is required to avoid dups

Comment: I want to set name when I ignore dublicate so I cant use hashset or etc.

Comment: but you do not ignore duplicate. You are adding them as well. Where do you remove them?

Comment: I know . I just share my code for you guys help me :)

Comment: which list do you display or whatever you do after the duplicates procedure? the infoListFiltered?

Comment: yes I want to collect my new list in infoListFiltered .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try out this way see if its work for you .

```
public void processData()  {
    List<Info> infoList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Info> infoListFiltered = new ArrayList<>();
    infoList.add(new Info("a",1, 2));
    infoList.add(new Info("b",2, 2));
    infoList.add(new Info("c",1, 3));
    infoList.add(new Info("d",1, 2));
    infoList.add(new Info("e",1, 2));
    for (Info info:infoList){
        int index=getDuplicateIndex(infoListFiltered,info);
        if(index==-1){
            infoListFiltered.add(info);
        }else{
            infoListFiltered.get(index).name+=","+info.name;
        }
    }
}

private int getDuplicateIndex(List<Info> infoListFiltered,Info info){
    for (int i = 0; i < infoListFiltered.size(); i++){
        if(infoListFiltered.get(i).height==info.height && infoListFiltered.get(i).weight==info.weight){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your own `equals` method in your `Info.class` (it is a good practice), 
and a setter such as:

```
public boolean equals(Info info) {
    return this.height == info.height && this.weight == info.weight;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Then in you `Main.class`, simply create another `Info` object with the name `"multi"` and the same `height` and `weight` and add it:

```
Info tmp = infoList.get(i);
if (tmp.equals(infoList.get(j))) {
    infoList.get(i).setName("multi");
    infoListFiltered.add(new Info("multi", tmp.height, tmp.weight));
} else {
    infoListFiltered.add(new Info(tmp.name, tmp.height, tmp.weight));
}
```

If you create another `Info` object you will have 2 different objects. The way you did you added the same object (e.g the same reference) so the name was changed in both of your lists.

Answer (score 0):

Use the contains Method of your ArrayList.
It compares the Object you give with the Objects in the ArrayList by using the equals Method you have to @Override in your Info Class.

Also there is a neat cheat Sheet from Rebellabs for Java Collections:
https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-collections-cheat-sheet/

Comment: I can ignore dublicate values in my list with collections framework but I stuck to add one item "name=multi" instead of add dublicate values

Comment: Search multiples and just add if you found the first by infoList.add(new Info("multi",1, 3)); and ask if you already got a multiple insertion by contains.

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing duplicate items from the infoListFiltered:

```
for (int i = 0; i < infoListFiltered.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < infoListFiltered.size(); j++) {
            if(infoListFiltered.get(i).name.equals(infoListFiltered.get(j).name)&&infoListFiltered.get(i).height==infoListFiltered.get(j).height&&infoListFiltered.get(i).weight==infoListFiltered.get(j).weight) {
                infoListFiltered.remove(j);
                j--; //adjust index on element removal
            }
        }
}
```

On Printing the infoListFiltered, you will get desired output

Answer (score 0):

probably a bit over complicated:

```
List<Info> infoListFiltered = infoList.stream().
       collect(
           // create a map with {height + " " + weight} as a key
           // and an Info object as result of reduction
           groupingBy(
                   i -> i.getHeight()+ " " + i.getWeight(), //use height + " " + weight as map key
                   collectingAndThen(
                           reducing(
                                   (a,b) -> new Info("multi", a.getHeight(), a.getWeight())
                                   // if there are 2 info with the same height and weight
                                   // create a new info object with name "multi"
                           ),
                           Optional::get
                   )
           )
       ).values().stream().collect(toList());

System.out.println(infoListFiltered);
// output [Info{name='multi', height=1, weight=2}, Info{name='c', height=1, weight=3}, Info{name='b', height=2, weight=2}]
```